# Nginx error 500 for wildcard over SSL

Tags: nginx, ssl

My problem is: 
going to https://{www,whatever}.mysite.com I got error 500.
going to http://mysite.com works fine

```
upstream my_server {
  server unix:/webapps/server/run/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen      80;
    server_name site.com www.site.com;
    return      301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {

    listen   443;
    server_name site.com *.site.com;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/ssl.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/ssl.key;


   location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            proxy_pass http://my_server;
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

Please advise.

Comment: So what was in the error log?

Comment: nothing - this is the most interesting... I only see get 500 in access.log

Comment: Check your application, then.

Comment: Aplication is ok.

Comment: nothing in error.log ?

Answer (score 0):

change `server_name site.com *.site.com;`

to
`server_name .site.com;`

according to [nginx doc](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html)

> Wildcard names
>
> A special wildcard name in the form “.example.org” can be used to match both the exact name “example.org” and the wildcard name “*.example.org”.

Comment: this solution didn't help

Comment: it was worth a try, if you have no other logs sorry, i have no further idea.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the problem may be on your backend handling the extra domains.

Maybe hardcode the original domain, prior to passing the request to the backend?

```
    proxy_set_header Host site.com;
```